# VPN with one nic

Tags: vpn

i want to use VPN and i follow this tutorial.
http://www.onecomputerguy.com/networking/w3k_vpn_server.htm

Everything works fine just i can not remote to my computer any more. Internet works but instead of my provider IP now i am using server VPN ip. Why? Why i can't use my standard provider IP.

Comment: What do you mean by "i am using server VPN ip"?  On which computer are you referring to a "standard provider IP"?  You need to add more details.

Comment: i create VPN server on computer with ip 193.17.23.31. When i connect VPn to this computer from my computer my ip will be changed to 193.17.23.31. My original ip is 87.123.25.87. Hope is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so the VPN work. When you connect to a VPN, virtually, you move to its local network. Then you use its Internet output instead of your provider.
If you want to continue using your provider, you should create static routes or configure your VPN to be used only for local IPs.